# where can I find data on web-research?

Tags: data-request

My purpose is to find a service (provide by Google or others) able to extract the frequencies of the web-researches of a website or a key term.
I know Google Trends but I would need a service that can look at the hierarchies (the terms correlated with my query) and that indicates also the geographical provenience.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if I understand 100% what you need/are asking, but common crawl has data like this:
https://commoncrawl.org/